# Laravel Eloquent query failes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Might be doing things wrong.

I have the following code:

*Controller:*

```
$this->data['topCommunities']   = Fanpages::topCommunities();
```

*Model:*

```
<?php

class Fanpages extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'fanpagestatistics';

    static function topCommunities()
    {
        return Fanpages::select('*')->orderBy('fans')->take(8);
    }
}
```

*View:*

```
<?php
 print_R($topCommunities);
 exit;
?>
```

And then it just shows me the white page. While, when I do an `print_r` in the model (followed by an exit ofcourse) it gives me a whole bunch of text, so there must be a result. Why is it doing this? Is my query wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add ->get(); to end of your query.

```
return Fanpages::select('*')->orderBy('fans')->take(8)->get();
```

Comment: I will go into my cave and shame the crap out of myself for seven days. I will write your name in the stars and I will never ever forget this answer. How could I be so blind? Thank you kind Sir/Madam. I will nominate you for a title.